# jboss-as-maven-plugin remote deployment to JBoss EAP- 6.4

Tags: maven, jenkins, jboss, jboss-eap-6

My Pom.xml is :

```
<build>
        <!-- Plugin Configuration -->
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!-- Deploy Plugin -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>7.9.Final</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <force>true</force>
                        <hostname>${jboss-as.deploy.hostname}</hostname>
                        <port>${jboss-as.deploy.portnumber}</port>
                        <username>${jboss-as.deploy.user}</username>
                        <password>${jboss-as.deploy.password}</password>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

I want to remote deploy this to another machine on my network and when i run:

```
mvn jboss-as:deploy -Djboss-as.deploy.hostname=192.168.1.150 -Djboss-as.deploy.portnumber=9999 -Djboss-as.deploy.username=testuser -Djboss-as.deploy.password=password
```

When i run the above deploy command from command line it asks for the remote machine password and when i enter the password, it deploys to the remote machine like this

```
Authenticating against security realm: ManagementRealm
Password:
```

As I want this to be setup as a jenkins job there it throws all authentication failed. I want this prompt to be stopped as passing the user name and password as an arguement.

Any suggestions on this and how to get this done as a jenkins job without asking for the remote EAP password again ??

Comment: What happens if you remove the entire `<configuration>...</configuration>` from the plugin definition and use `-Djboss-as.hostname=192.168.1.150 -Djboss-as.port=9999 -Djboss-as.username=testuser -Djboss-as.password=password` on the command line? These are the properties defined by the plugin BTW, rather than yours

Comment: i want that to be deployed remotely so am specifying that in hostname if i remove everything it deploys locally not to the remote server

Comment: Using the **exact** argument list that I provided?

Comment: when i remove and run it as you mentioned i get this error :

Could not execute goal deploy on /jenkins/workspace/init_eap/core-services/target/core-services.war. Reason: I/O Error could not execute operation '{
[ERROR] "operation" => "read-attribute",
[ERROR] "address" => [],
[ERROR] "name" => "launch-type"
[ERROR] }': java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to remote://localhost:9999. The connection timed out

see its printing remote://localhost:9999 not remote://192.168.1.150:9999

Comment: Do you have the plugin defined in the `<plugins/>` section? The example above is in the `<pluginManagement/>` section.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins i have it as it is there in above code. Dont we need pluginManagement do i need to remove and try ?

Comment: You have to have it defined in your `<build><plugins/></build>` section of your pom otherwise it won't work. That goes for ALL maven plugins. https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management